# python decorator doesn't take the arguments of the function

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm learning python and I'm stuck at decorators
the way I understand it is that decorators add functionality to a function
I made a simple function that checks if a number is even
and then a decorator that adds taking the absolute value to it

```
def decorate(func):
    def is_even_new(*args,**kwargs):
        num = abs(*args,**kwargs)
        func(num)
    return is_even_new()

@decorate 
def is_even(x):
    if x%2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

is_even(8)
```

but it I keep getting a TypeError: abs() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
is there is something wrong in the code or is my understanding of decorators is false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you decorate the function, you should return the decorated function itself:

```py
def decorate(func):
    def is_even_new(*args,**kwargs):
        num = abs(*args,**kwargs)
        func(num)

    return is_even_new
```

rather than *calling* the decorated function and returning that:

```py
def decorate(func):
    def is_even_new(*args,**kwargs):
        num = abs(*args,**kwargs)
        func(num)

    return is_even_new()
```

(notice the extra parentheses). In this last example, when you decorate a function with `@decorate`, the decorator defines this inner function `is_even_new` and then, instead of returning the latter, it tries to call it with no arguments: `is_even_new()`. This is also why you're getting the `TypeError`: `abs` expects (exactly) one argument, but you've given it none.

Remember that functions in Python are objects like anything else ("first-class citizens") and so you can reference them directly by their name.

Also, as a recommendation, if you know that the functions decorated with `@decorate` will only ever take exactly one argument (like `is_even`), don't use variable arguments and keyword arguments, just define the decorate function to take exactly one parameter as well:

```py
import functools


def decorate(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def decorated(x):
        func(abs(x))

    return decorated
```

This will make the error messages more helpful (instead of raising at the `abs` call,

Or, if you only want to apply `abs` to, say, the first argument:

```py
def decorate(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def decorated(x, *args, **kwargs):
        func(abs(x), *args, **kwargs)

    return decorated
```

You'll also have noticed the [`@functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps). This is a very useful standard library utility for defining wrapper functions, such as those you return from a decorator. It sets special attributes like `__name__`, `__module__`, etc. on the wrapper function so that it essentially looks like the wrapped function.

Answer (score 0):

in your  code you need to return the value from the decorator in correct way and also change the input data to the decorator by keeping the limitation of other inside function in mind ie (abs take 1 positonal argument not many) and you cant directly call the return function from outside as full without provideing value as `return is_new_even()`, you need to pass the argument there also if want to do that way

```
def decorate(func):
    def is_even_new(val):
        num = abs(val)
        return func(num)
    return is_even_new 

@decorate 
def is_even(x):
    if x%2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

is_even(8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your decorated function is trying to do as modulo is working on negative integers as well, but you basically have two problems:

1. like @Anakhand said you should return a function and not the function return value.
2. your `is_even_new` does not return nothing

so I guess this is the correct implemntation:

```
def decorate(func):
    def is_even_new(*args,**kwargs):
        num = abs(*args,**kwargs)
        return func(num)
    return is_even_new

@decorate
def is_even(x):
    if x%2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(is_even(-8))  # --> True
```

Comment: the decorated function was trying to get the absolute value because the original function was a recursive function that was subtracting two from the number (i was trying to understand recursion as well) 
i just changed it for clarification  :"